# Automatic search engine manipulation

Tags: python, search

I have an idea to make a program (in python) that will search for me. I won't put the details in here, but basically, its somewhat of an automatic search. The only part that I don't quite understand is how will I actually make it search. I can figure out how to open and display the search, but I don't quite understand how I will "find" the text box and imput something into it.

Basically my question is: how will I get the search engine to input something into the search field and search it?

If this is to "wide" of a question, please delete it (if possible).

Comment: Are you talking about web pages? So basically you are trying to write a browser? :)

Comment: try: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: @freakish not exactly. I want a "bot" that just opens one search engine page and automatically searches.

Comment: @Elazar thats nice. Anything similar for bing? I'll see what I can do with google, and if I can use it with python...

Comment: I did something similar before, I used `PyQt4`. And the final version looked like google in cmd =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few ways you can do this

you can use urllib2 which wont open a browser window but it will just get the information

or you can use something like selenium which will show the window but it is much easier to input into forms

i would use urllib because its faster because you dont have to load the page and its alot "cleaner" because its in the background

what you need to do is send something called a POST request which will send data from the user to the search engine youre using. but you need to find the name of the form you are inputting into which on search engines is usually q but might be different after you submit the data you need to get the info from the page using a scraper like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to get the information from the search and return it

Im not going to write out the code but there are examples and alot of info in the [Urllib2 Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

Good Luck!!

Comment: It's probably best to use an API, where offered - Google has one for relatively low-volume usage. Much easier than scraping approaches, which run the risk of being blocked.